# How do I merge my StreamProvider and my GlobalsProvider into one?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-provider

I started my project by following a tutorial that handles the Firebase auth using a Stream. Later on, I start using my own GlobalsProvider to hold any shared variables that must be updated/propagated in real time. I now want to merge all of this into just the GlobalsProvider class so that all provider stuff is in one file. How would I do this?

**main.dart:**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseHelper.init();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<GlobalsProvider>(
      create: (context) => GlobalsProvider(),
      lazy: false, //If true, create/update callbacks won't be called until the value is requested at least once. Therefore, this is set to false so that it runs right away
      child: Consumer<GlobalsProvider>(
        builder: (context, globalsProvider, child) => StreamProvider<ModelAuthUser?>.value(
          value: AuthService().user,
          initialData: null,
          child: const GetMaterialApp(
            title: 'MyApp',
            home: Wrapper(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**auth.dart:**

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String get currentUser => _auth.currentUser!.uid;
  final staticGlobals = StaticGlobals();

  // create CurrentUser object based on Firebase user object
  UserModel.ModelAuthUser? _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user) {
    if (user != null) {
      return UserModel.ModelAuthUser(uid: user.uid, username: '');
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  //auth change user stream
  Stream<UserModel.ModelAuthUser?> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

  //...other auth functions...

}
```

**globals_provider.dart:**

```
class GlobalsProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  //Variables that can change:
  String currentUID = ''; //The Firebase uid
  String currentUsername = ''; //Username from Firestore
  final sqlDir = '';
  final sqlDBPath = '';
  sql.Database? sqlDB;

  void updateState() {
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**modelAuthUser.dart**

```
class ModelAuthUser {
  final String uid;
  String username = ''; //Empty during Firebase Auth. Afterwards, this should be filled with the value from Firestore

  ModelAuthUser({
    required this.uid,
    required this.username
  });

  ModelAuthUser.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic>? json): //Transform JSON into model
        uid = json?['uid'] as String,
        username = json?['username'] as String;

  Map<dynamic, dynamic> toJson() => <dynamic, dynamic>{ //Transforms model into JSON
    'uid': uid,
    'username': username,
  };

}
```